# javascript validation rules not working

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following code and the validation rules aren't working, any help please! The web browser does not recognise the javascript code as the active x control doesn't seem to appear.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>

<script lanuage="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var result = true;

function validateForm() {

    var msg="";

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
        msg+="you must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }
    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
        msg+("You must enter the subject \n");
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result false;
    }
    if (document.ExamEntry.ExaminationNumber.value=="") {
        msg+("You must enter the Examination Number \n");
        document.ExamEntry.ExaminationNumber.focus();
        document.getElementById('ExaminationNumber').style.color="red";
        result false;
    }
    if(msg==""){
    return result;
    }

    {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
    }
}
</script>
<form>
        <input type="radio" name="qualification" value="GCSE">GCSE<br>
        <input type="radio" name="qualification" value="AS">AS<br>
        <input type="radio" name="qualification" value="A2">A2<br>
</form>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="name">Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="subject">Subject</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td id="ExaminationNumber">ExaminationNumber</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ExaminationNumber" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
    <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Please could someone help, this is driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '=' sign on line 23 and 29
`result false;` should be `result = false;`

Tip: You can check you js errors in your browser's developer console.

Update: Ok, the following works fine when I test it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exam entry</title>

    <script lanuage="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var result = true;

        function validateForm() {

            var msg = "";

            if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
                msg += "you must enter your name \n";
                document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
                document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }
            if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
                msg + ("You must enter the subject \n");
                document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
                document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }
            if (document.ExamEntry.ExaminationNumber.value == "") {
                msg + ("You must enter the Examination Number \n");
                document.ExamEntry.ExaminationNumber.focus();
                document.getElementById('ExaminationNumber').style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }
            if (msg == "") {
                return result;
            }

            {
                alert(msg)
                return result;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
    <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
        <table style="width: 50%;" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td id="name">Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="ExaminationNumber">ExaminationNumber</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ExaminationNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for some reason i have done in my original one but not on here is anything else wrong?

Comment: They are in but still not working, any more help? The javascript is running as it is changing the colour but not showing the error message?

Comment: @SamanthaMclemon: You are writing `msg + (...)` in a couple of places when you probably mean `msg += (...)`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few reasons the code snippet in your question will fail. Let me point out some flaws:

1. There shouldn't be a form in the head section
2. `document.ExamEntry` is invalid. Correct would be `document.forms['ExamEntry']`
3. Something like `document.ExamEntry.subject` is not possible. Chaining child nodes does not work. The DOM needs to be traversed using the DOM methods provided. I suggest reading a tutorial such as http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/javascript-and-the-dom-series-lesson-1/

I have modified the JavaScript and included a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tangibleJ/JgX8h/) to make the validation work. It is a quick fix. I added a helper function called `getInputByName`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getInputByName(inputName) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0, ii = inputs.length, input; i < ii, input = inputs[i]; i++) {
        if (input.name === inputName) {
            return input
        }
    }
    return false;
}



function validateForm() {

    var result = true;

    var msg="";

    if (getInputByName('name').value=="") {
        msg+="you must enter your name \n";
        getInputByName('name').focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }


    if (getInputByName('subject').value=="") {
        msg+("You must enter the subject \n");
        getInputByName('subject').focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (getInputByName('ExaminationNumber').value=="") {
        msg+("You must enter the Examination Number \n");
        getInputByName('ExaminationNumber').focus();
        document.getElementById('ExaminationNumber').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if (msg == ""){
        return result;
    } else {
        alert(msg)
        return result;
    }
}
</script>
```